# Postgres Database flagged as STORAGE FULL whereas there's 45 Gb available

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, postgresql-9.6, aws, storage

I will start this post by stating that I am not very experienced in database administration, please accept my apologies for any unclear explanation you may find below.

We have a replica postgresql hosted on AWS RDS, which stopped replicating last week. The instance was flagged as **Storage-full**.

However, while looking at the free storage space on *CloudWatch*, we realized there were still roughly 46Gb available on the 50Gb-allocated instance. We increased the allocated space to 60Gb and everything went back to normal, but we knew the issue would come back and it did.

The main instance on which this one is replicated is auto vacuumed. I think  any writes resulting on the main will be written on the replica, so this is probably not a vacuum issue.

I could not find any indication of problem in *CloudWatch* metrics.

It appears that the logs could be the issue here but I don't know where to look to investigate this option.

I will edit the question with any relevant information you might suggest in the comments.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! Can you run `du -h` from the various directories under root on your AWS instance to check the space usage of the various systems?

Comment: Hi Vérace, thanks for taking a look at this. I can ssh into the db instance via `psql` but I can't find the information to ssh into the instance itself. It should be no more difficult than ssh-ing into an ec2 instance but I can't find proper information on that matter

Comment: Still - it's a bit wierd - when you pay for 50GB, shouldn't you get 50GB of useful space - i.e. not including the OS itself? Just a heads up - **not** a cloud person really - am planning to move though!

Comment: That was my initial thought.. But it appears the free storage metric from AWS RDS represents the storage taken by the tables of the database and not the volume itself. (I checked using `SELECT pg_database_size('mydb');` and numbers match) Logs might be the issue but I can't get access to the information..

Comment: 45GB of logs seems a bit excessive! :-) Don't they have an email helpline? If you do get a response, post back here with the answer - it might help others with the same issue! You can answer your own question and also mark it correct - no points though! :-) Just had a thought - you can run shell commands from `psql`! [`Shell excitement with the \! psql meta-command.`](https://codeburst.io/shell-excitement-with-the-psql-meta-command-a04d2a2a4c)?

Comment: See https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/diskfull-error-rds-postgresql/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Vérace, I'll answer the question if I find the answer for sure ! however the \! command let me run shell commands on my current shell (the one executing `psql`) and not the remote one (where `psql` is executed)

Comment: @DanielVérité thanks for the link, already had a look at it and checked everything, everything looks like it should not be in "Storage Full" state...

Comment: What, exactly, are you doing on the master OLTP/OLAP? Do you absolutely require RDS? You **could** set up a bare metal instance and then you'd have much more control? Maybe run a bare metal instance temporarily - find the problem, deal with it and **then** switch back to RDS if you find that service better/more to your liking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got an answer back from AWS support.

It appears the problem came from not having enough space left for inodes. We cannot control allocated space for inodes on RDS so the only solution here is to get a bigger instance.

The OOM Killer allowed to get our instance running again.